# How to prove x = 8 is the only solution to $\frac{3}{\sqrt{3x - 8} +1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 1} + 2} = \frac{2}{5}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\begin{array}{l}\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{3x - 8} +1} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x + 1} + 2} = \dfrac{2}{5}\qquad (*)\\ (x \geq \dfrac{8}{3})\\ (*) \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{3(\sqrt{3x - 8} - 1)}{(\sqrt{3x - 8} + 1)(\sqrt{3x - 8} - 1)} - \dfrac{\sqrt{x + 1} - 2}{(\sqrt{x + 1} + 2)(\sqrt{x + 1} - 2)} = \dfrac{2}{5}\\ \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{\sqrt{3x - 8} - 1}{x - 3} - \dfrac{\sqrt{x + 1} - 2}{x - 3} = \dfrac{2}{5}\\ \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{3x - 8} - \sqrt{x + 1} + 1 = \dfrac{2}{5}(x - 3)\\ \Leftrightarrow (\sqrt{3x - 8} - 4) - (\sqrt{x + 1} - 3) = \dfrac{2}{5}(x- 8)\\ \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{3x - 24}{\sqrt{3x - 8} + 4} - \dfrac{x - 8}{\sqrt{x + 1} + 3} = \dfrac{2}{5}(x - 8)\\ \Leftrightarrow (x - 8)\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{3x - 8} + 4} -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x + 1} + 3} - \dfrac{2}{5}\right) = 0\\ \Leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{l}x - 8 = 0\\\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{3x - 8} + 4} -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x + 1} + 3} - \dfrac{2}{5} = 0\end{array}\right.\\\Leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{l}x = 8\\x = 3\end{array}\right.\end{array}$

Comment: I think I did something wrong in somewhere, please help me find it

Comment: If x=3, then whenever you multiply by the conjugate in the beginning, you're multiply by 0/0, so the if and only if doesn't hold.

Comment: I'm sorry but how is this a differential equation?

Comment: please enumerate the equations to make the discussion easier

Comment: In the denominator, you write x-3, that's because x≠3 (you can see it on the 4th line)

Answer (score 1):

The domain gives $x\geq\frac{8}{3}.$

Now, we need to solve:
$$\frac{3}{\sqrt{3x-8}+1}-\frac{3}{5}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+2}-\frac{1}{5}$$ or
$$\frac{3(4-\sqrt{3x-8})}{\sqrt{3x-8}+1}=\frac{3-\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1}+2}$$ or
$$(8-x)\left(\frac{9}{(4+\sqrt{3x-8})(1+\sqrt{3x-8})}-\frac{1}{(3+\sqrt{x+1})(2+\sqrt{x+1})}\right)=0,$$
which gives $x=8$ only because
$$9(3+\sqrt{x+1})(2+\sqrt{x+1})=$$
$$=(3\sqrt3+\sqrt{3x+3})(6\sqrt3+3\sqrt{3x+3})>$$
$$>(4+\sqrt{3x-8})(1+\sqrt{3x-8}).$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Phước Vinh  You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

When plotting your first and third-last equation (from [original Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840855/how-to-prove-x-8-is-the-only-solution-to-frac3-sqrt3x-8-1-frac1)) yields:

[image]

You can see that $g(x)$ has two valid solutions i.e. $x = \{3, 8\}$ where as $f(x)$ has only one solution at $x = \{8\}$. Shouldn't these both functions look identical?